# Transforming a plane onto another plane via matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a transformation $$T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
4&-5&0\\
-1&2&0\\
-3&-5&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$ is used to transform $\Pi_1$ onto $\Pi_2$ with equation $2x-z=4$ How do I find $\Pi_1$?

I tried :

$$\begin{align}TA&=A'\\T^{-1}TA&=T^{-1}A'\end{align}$$

So

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -5 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 \\
-3 & -5 & -1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 0 \\ -1
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{3}
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ 2\\ -19
\end{pmatrix}$$

How do I use the fact that $2x-z=\color{red}{4}$ to finish the problem? Is the answer just $\Pi_1 : r\cdot\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 2 \\ -19\end{pmatrix}=4$?

Comment: It could be useful to look at a parametric expression of your plane (for example $x=t, y=u, z=2t-4$) and apply $T^{-1}$ to such vectors $(t, u, 2t-4)$.

Comment: Find two vectors that span $\Pi_1$, say $v_1$ and $v_2$, then apply $T$ to $v_1$ and $v_2$. By doing this you have that $w_1=T(v_1)$ and $w_2=T(v_2)$ span $\Pi_2$. Use any point of $\Pi_1$ to find a point of $\Pi_2$ by applying $T$ to it. With two generators and a point you will be able to find the equation for $\Pi_2$.

Comment: It is wrong to assume that the image of the normal to the first plane is the normal to the second plane. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be any point on the plane $\Pi_1$, and let the image of this point under the transformation $T$ be $(x,y,z)$ which lies on $\Pi_2$. So $$T\left(\begin{matrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\end{matrix}\right)$$

Multiplying the matrix out, we get $$x=4X-5Y$$ and $$z=-3X-5Y-Z$$

Now substitute these expressions into the equation of $\Pi_2$, namely $2x-z=4$, and you get the equation of $\Pi_1$ which is $$11X-5Y+Z=4$$

Note that the inverse of $T$ is not required for this calculation, but would be if you were trying to find the image, under $T$, of a **given** plane expressed in Cartesian form.

Comment: +1, Simple and elegant!!

Answer (score 1):

If $2x - z = 4$ is the equation of a plane $\Pi_2$, then we know that point $q_0 = (2,0,0)$ is on $\Pi_2$ as $2(2) - 0 = 4$. We also know that the vector $n_2 = (2,0,-1)$ is normal to the plane $\Pi_2$ as

\begin{align*}
n_2 \cdot (\textbf{x} - q_0) &=  0 \\
2(x - 2) - (z - 0) &= 0 \\
2x - z &= 4,
\end{align*}

as desired. That is, every vector on the plane is perpendicular to the normal vector, a standard result in a multivariable calculus class.

Our goal now is to find $n_1 = T^{-1} n_2$, the normal vector of $\Pi_1$. We calculate the inverse of $T$ first. The determinant of $A = \text{Mat}(T)$ is

\begin{equation}
\det A = 4(-2) + 5 = 5 - 8 = -3
\end{equation}

The adjoint of $A$ is
\begin{align*}
\text{Ad } A &= \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 5+6 \\
-(5 - 0) & -4 - 0 & -(-20 - 15) \\
0 & 0 & 8-5 
\end{pmatrix}^T \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 11\\
-5 & -4 & 35 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}^T  \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -5 & 0 \\
-1 & -4 & 0 \\
11 & 35 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, the inverse of $T$ is
\begin{equation}
T^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A} \text{Ad } A = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & 0 \\
1 & 4 & 0 \\
-11 & -35 & -3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

We then have that
\begin{align*}
n_1 &= T^{-1} n_2 \\
&=  \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 2 \\ -19\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

We also know that a point on $\Pi_1$ is $p_0 = T^{-1} q_0$. We then have that
\begin{align*}
p_0 &= T^{-1} q_0 \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 2 \\ -22 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Finally, we know that $n_1 \cdot (\textbf{x} - p_0) = 0$ is the equation of $\Pi_1.$ We calculate that

\begin{align*}
4x + 2y - 19z &= -16
\end{align*}

Comment: It is wrong to assume that the image of the normal to the first plane is the normal to the second plane

Comment: Why is that? I love your answer and method regardless.

Comment: Because generally matrix transformations will involve some element of **shear** so that cuboids are transformed into parallelipipeds. So the normal to the first plane, when transformed, will not necessarily be normal to the image plane.